# i don't understand what i am doing wrong. (line 29)

Tags: python

[image]

my problem is that i can't use elipse in line 29 ore someting like that.
line 29 = elife player_choice == '2':

Comment: Please post code, not screenshots of code. (That's easier for you and makes it simpler for us to help you.

Comment: You're using a `elif` out of nowhere, not following another `elif` or `if`. I fail to see the logic of what you're trying to do so it's hard for me to help you further.

Comment: You might want to start with drawing a [flowchart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) of what behaviour you're after, then code that. The `elif` you have should go after the `if`, but you have some behaviour in the `else`, which should most likely go somewhere else, but since you have a second `else`... ???

Answer (score 2):

There is an else wrong indent in line 21. Add one more tab to it and in its code block. After try to rebuild.

Python use identation to make code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

add one more tab before **elif** and prew lines.

Tabs is very impotent in python

the same numbers tabbed mean code in the same logical block

in your case **if** and **elif** is in different blocks but must be in the same

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained why this tab is needed, so users reading it understand not just how to solve this one error case, but how to avoid similar errors in future.